# Docker on several hosts (Windows and Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-desktop, docker-engine

I have 2 hosts with Docker: Ubuntu and Windows(docker-desktop). I want to connect a container with Adminer(Windows) to a container with MariaDB(Ubuntu). **Is it possible?** 
My hosts locate in the same local network, and containers are isolated from each other(of course). I was trying to create overlay network and to bind between each other, but worker's message has been:   "docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded."
  My goal is to make communication between different host containers. Please, can you help me with my problem :)

Comment: Have you tried to just expose the port and use <host_ip>:<exposed_port> to connect from one to another?

Comment: Any TCP port can be mapped to any host regardingless of the operating system. This is on what the internet is built on.

Answer (score 0):

- **Important:** Make sure your host machines can communicate with each other over the network, and there are no issues due to network firewalls, etc.
- Looks like need to bind the port of your container to your host machine.
- When you are running your Docker containers use the -p option. You can find a lot of examples at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/.
- After you have exposed your containers port, you can access them using `<host-machine-ip>:<host-machine-port-you-used-to-bind-container>`